# Getting error while using gds.alpha.graphSage.stream in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

While trying to run the gds algorythm it is throwing error

```
CALL gds.alpha.graphSage.stream(
  'persons',
  {
    nodePropertyNames: ['age', 'height', 'weight'],
    aggregator: 'mean',
    activationFunction: 'sigmoid',
    embeddingSize: 3,
    sampleSizes: [25, 10],
    degreeAsProperty: true
  }
)
```

> There is no procedure with the name `gds.alpha.graphSage.stream`
> registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled
> the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly
> deployed.

Comment: Are you using Neo4j Desktop? If so, have you installed the "Graph Data Science Library
" plugin there?

Comment: Hi i am using neo4j desk top. I have installed GDS library 1.4,neo4j version is 4.2.0

Answer (score 0):

It seems the procedure is now in the beta tier: https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/graph-sage/#algorithms-embeddings-graph-sage-syntax.

It should be `gds.beta.graphSage.stream`.